# calling MATLAB function from Python, what is Python's equivalent of MATLAB 'matrix' datatype?

Tags: python, matlab

This question relates to the situation where only MATLAB runtime is present - the computer does not have a full MATLAB license.

A MATLAB function has been compiled for use by Python as described [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-python-application-with-matlab-code.html):

These instructions have been used successfully to call a user defined MATLAB function from Python and get a return value where parameters are `int` or `float`.  However, if I call a user defined MATLAB function `f(matrixParam)` which has a parameter of MATLAB type `matrix` then no matter what data type I use in Python for it, I get wrong type errors.  I tried the following Python types: list of lists (`[[1,2],[3,4]]`), Pandas.DataFrame and NumPy.matrix - nothing works.  In MATLAB a variable `a` of type `matrix` may be defined like this:  `a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 10]`.

Would anyone know how I would define in Python a variable that would be acceptable by a MATLAB function as being of type `matrix`?

Comment: That seems specific to the function you used.

Comment: Could you give an example of Python that calls a MATLAB function with a parameter of type 'matrix' where it doesn't throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be:

```
import matlab

myMatrix = matlab.double([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

`myMatrix` can then be passed to a MATLAB function.  MATLAB will even get True if it tests its type: `ismatrix(myMatrix)`.